# How do I destruct a map and populate a map pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, destructor, stdmap

If we create a `map<int,int>`, we can clear it but it still stays in memory, right? E.g.

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    map<int,int> myMap;
    myMap[1] = 2;
    myMap.clear();

return 0;
}
```

But if we set a pointer instead of the actual `map`, I could destruct it with `delete`, but I couldn't populate the map the same way:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    map<int,int> *myMap = new map<int,int>;
    // myMap[1] = 2;
    delete myMap;

return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting the `myMap[1] = 2;` line ends up with the error:

> alvas@ubi:~$ g++ test.cpp 
>       test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>       test.cpp:8:14: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map’ and ‘int’)
>            myMap[1] = 2;
>                     ^
>       In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/map:61:0,
>                        from test.cpp:2:
>       /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:296:7: note: candidate: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
>   _Alloc>::operator=(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less; _Alloc = std::allocator >]
>              operator=(const map& __x)
>              ^
>       /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_map.h:296:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘int’ to ‘const std::map&’

How do I destruct a `map` in C++? Is it "destructable"?

Also, How do I initialize/populate the values of a `map<>` pointer?

Comment: `(*myMap)[1] = 2;` does the trick if you use `new`. The rest is in CinCout answer below

Comment: Same reason `int *i = new int(0); i += 5; delete i;` doesn't add 5 to the `int`.

Comment: *"If we create a `map<int,int>`, we can clear it but it still stays in memory, right?"*, the map management object itself does (which is likely one or two dozen bytes, depending on whether you're compiling a 32 bit or 64 bit app and whether the `map` implementation added data to support debugging) but the memory for the data elements the `map` used to store will be released for reuse by the application.  Summarily, it's very rarely worth doing more than a `clear` on a `map`.  That contrasts with `vector` which tends to hang on to memory where elements used to be stored.

Comment: Go the first route. When you clear a map, its content is gone. It occupies then no more storage than a pointer to it would (well, maybe  just *a little* bit more). Don't complicate your code unnecessarily.

Comment: You have 15K rep. You should know to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I destruct a map in C++?

When you declare it as an object (first case), it gets destroyed when it goes out of scope.

When declared as a pointer, `delete` keyword does the trick if `new` is used. If smart pointers are used, there's no need to explicitly call `delete`.

> How do I initialize/populate the values of a map<> pointer?

Use the [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) method, like this:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    map<int,int> *myMap = new map<int,int>;
    myMap->insert(make_pair<int, int>(1, 2));
    delete myMap;

return 0;
}
```

Or, as suggested by @Michael, you can use `(*myMap)[1] = 2;` But I prefer using the API.

NOTE: As pointed out in the comments, [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) and `insert()` for a `std::map` aren't similar in terms of behavior. It's just that, in this minimal example, they don't reflect any difference.

Comment: ^And how does that affect in this context?

Comment: By omitting that crucial detail, your answer suggests they are equivalent, and they aren't.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can release the memory a `std::map` is using (to its initial minimum) without resorting to pointers.

First is the idiomatic *clear and minimize* (swap) whereby you create an empty temporary map and *swap* its contents with your working map:

```
std::map<int,int>().swap(myMap); // memory reset to minimum
```

The other method is to control the scope of the map using an internal scope  `{` and `}`.

```
int func()
{
    { // <- start an internal scope for the map

        std::map<int,int> myMap;

        // use the map

    } // <- let the map go out of scope when done using it

    // carry on without the map
}
```

If you *must* use a pointer (best avoided) then you need to *dereference* the pointer using `*` like so:

```
(*myMap)[key] = value;
```